# Taipy’s output collapsed in Visual Studio Code notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, taipy

I’have tried to run code about displaying some things with taipy.gui but it had an error and didn’t give me the output desired
exercise code:

```
page_md = “””
# Taipy

Test **here** to put some *markdown*

Click to access the [doc](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/)
“””
page = Markdown(page_md)

gui = Gui(page=page)
gui.run(dark_mode=False)
```

Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

> ArgumentError Traceback (most recent call last)
> File c:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\argparse.py:1859, in ArgumentParser.parse_known_args(self, args, namespace)
> 1858 try:
> -> 1859 namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
> 1860 except ArgumentError:
> File c:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\argparse.py:2068, in ArgumentParser._parse_known_args(self, arg_strings, namespace)
> 2067 # consume the next optional and any arguments for it
> -> 2068 start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
> 2070 # consume any positionals following the last Optional
> File c:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\argparse.py:1990, in ArgumentParser._parse_known_args..consume_optional(start_index)
> 1989 msg = _(‘ignored explicit argument %r’)
> -> 1990 raise ArgumentError(action, msg % explicit_arg)
> 1992 # if there is no explicit argument, try to match the
> 1993 # optional’s string arguments with the following strings
> 1994 # if successful, exit the loop
> 1995 else:
> ArgumentError: argument –force-https: ignored explicit argument ‘c:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-8784auLjxl5B1eB3.json’

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> SystemExit Traceback (most recent call last)
> …
> 170 if isinstance(error, str):
> 171 error = AssertionError(error)
> –> 172 raise error

AssertionError:

could anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to some incompatibility between VS Code notebook and Taipy. It has been solved in the new releases. Upgrade your Taipy version, and this issue will disappear.